# Android autocompletion view using retrofit

Tags: android, adapter, retrofit, searchview, autocompletetextview

I'm trying to understand how to implement a search with chips (so there should be the chance to add more than one value) and the suggestion list should come from a web service using Retrofit. An example on what I would like to achieve is the search in Pinterest app.

I read online many post where someone uses AutoCompleteTextView and other SearchView and to be honest I'm very confused on which approach to follow.

Could you address me to the right way please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is code example of using `Retrofit` with `AutocompleteEditText`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private interface GooglePlacesClient {

        @GET("/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json")
        Observable<PlacesResult> autocomplete(
            @Query("key") String key,
            @Query("input") String input);
    }

    private class PlacesResult {
        @Expose
        List<MainActivity.Prediction> predictions;
        @Expose
        String status;
    }

    private class Prediction {
        @Expose
        String description;
    }

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "RxRetrofitAutoComplete";
    private static final String GOOGLE_API_BASE_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com";
    private static final String API_KEY = "XXX";
    private static final int DELAY = 500;

    GooglePlacesClient mGooglePlacesClient;

    @InjectView(R.id.editText1)
    EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);

        if (API_KEY.length()<10) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "API KEY is unset!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        if (mGooglePlacesClient == null) {
            mGooglePlacesClient = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                    .setConverter(new GsonConverter(new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create()))
                    .setEndpoint(GOOGLE_API_BASE_URL)
                    .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL).build()
                    .create(GooglePlacesClient.class);
        }

        Observable<EditText> searchTextObservable = ViewObservable.text(editText);
        searchTextObservable.debounce(DELAY, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .map(new Func1<EditText, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String call(EditText editText) {
                        return editText.getText().toString();
                    }
                })
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(String s) {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, s);
                        try {
                            mGooglePlacesClient
                                    .autocomplete(API_KEY, URLEncoder.encode(s, "utf8"))
                                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                    .subscribe(new Action1<PlacesResult>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void call(PlacesResult placesResult) {
                                            List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
                                            for (MainActivity.Prediction p : placesResult.predictions) {
                                                strings.add(p.description);
                                            }
                                            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                                            if (listView != null) {
                                                listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strings));
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                                            throwable.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    });
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                        throwable.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```